# Не работает код в Tampermonkey

Tags: javascript

Имею достаточно простой кусок кода:

```html
<html>
<head>

</head>
<body>

    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type="text" id="txt" autofocus placeholder="Введи номер">
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type="button" value="Поиск" onClick='location.href="http://site.lan/SearchByNumber.aspx?text=" + txt.value'>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>

</body>
</html>
```

и если я его сохраняю отдельным html файлом, то все работает и при нажатии кнопки происходит переход на новую страницу с подстановкой нужного значения из текстового поля.

Когда же я вставляю код в скрипт Tampermonkey, то он перестает работать. Вот код скрипта:

```js
(function() {
    'use strict';
    let divLast = document.createElement('td');
    divLast.innerHTML = '<div id="Search_panel">'+
    '<table><tr><td><input type="text" id="txt" autofocus placeholder="Введи номер"></td></tr>' + '<tr><td></td></tr>' +
    '<tr><td><input type="button" value="Поиск" onClick='location.href="http://site.lan/SearchByNumber.aspx?text=" + txt.value'></td></tr></table>'
    workPlace.before(divLast);
    })();
```

Визуально инъекция html происходит, но кнопка не переводит на новую страницу.

Я с JS не очень силен. Может быть подскажете в чем может быть проблема?

Comment: добро пожаловать на stack overflow на русском! [как задать хороший вопрос](//ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Этот код вообще синтаксически некорректен: вы завернули html-код в одинарные кавычки, при этом после `onClick=` у вас тоже стоит одинарная кавычка, и в итоге весь синтаксис ломается

Comment: @andreymal может быть у вас есть примеры рабочего innerhtml со вставками js?
Что-то я не могу понять как мне правильно нужные кавыки накидать в скрипт :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Используйте обратные кавычки:

```
(function() {
    'use strict';
    let divLast = document.createElement('td');
    divLast.innerHTML = '<div id="Search_panel">'+
    '<table><tr><td><input type="text" id="txt" autofocus placeholder="Введи номер"></td></tr>' + '<tr><td></td></tr>' +
    `<tr><td><input type="button" value="Поиск" onClick='location.href="http://site.lan/SearchByNumber.aspx?text=" + txt.value'></td></tr></table>`
    workPlace.before(divLast);
})();
```

Comment: Спасибо!
Все получилось.